# Screen / Canvas height for Gear S not getting correct

Tags: samsung-galaxy-gear

I am trying to  port one of my Gear 2 apps to Gear S.
I copied the app with a new name and then changed width/height settings in index.html , config.xml 
The width gets correctly fitted (360px)
But the height doesn't fit. It stays like the height is not 480 but 360. There are black marging on bottom anfd top.
How can I start from top 0 ?

ps. I have abackground which is set to 100% fit

```
.canvas#cnvs { 
    width:100%;
    heigth:100%;
    background: url(../images/BG_PART.png);   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the following line in my config.xml

```
<preference name="view-compat" value="square"/>
```

it is solved when I remove this.